# Karate data driven with xml and son

Tags: automation, karate

I'm new to automation and started with Karate Framework.

I want to parametrize random and countrycode for different test data. How to do that with xml and json?

My json requests are bulky and need multiple parameterizations

Scenario: create User

```
def createuserrequest = read('classpath:com/imscreateuser/createuser.xml')
Given url imscreateuserurl
And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
And request createuserrequest 
When method post
Then status 200
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReqBody version="1.9.11"  options="prettyOutput">
   <req dest="UserManagement" api="createPerson">
      <Person>
         <countryCode>'#(countrycode)'</countryCode>
         <credentials class="Credentials">
            <password>P@ssword1</password>
            <username>new+'#(random)'@testing.com</username>
         </credentials>
      </Person>
      <AuthRequest />
   </req>
</ReqBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<countryCode>'#(countrycode)'</countryCode>` is wrong. It should be `<countryCode>#(countrycode)</countryCode>`.

And `<username>new+'#(random)'@testing.com</username>` is wrong. It should be `<username>#('new' + random + '@testing.com')</username>`.

Look at this example for XML ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature

For parameterization, you would not be asking this question if you have read the docs. Refer this section: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests

And look at this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature

Find the Karate demo examples and look at the `dynamic-params.feature`.